# Finding vertices without a particular edge with gremlin

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I'm able to find all of my `tag` vertex points which have an edge labeled `tagged` using:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('tag').inE().hasLabel('tagged')
==>e[eas0-109ds-e8l-y8oo][1691776-tagged->1597560]
==>e[ed5c-109ds-e8l-1181s][1691776-tagged->1736704]
```

Now, I would like to remove all of the `tag` vertices which do not have an edge labeled `tagged`.  When I use this command to find these vertices:

`gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('tag').inE().hasNot('label', 'tagged')`

I get the error message `No signature of method: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.DefaultGraphTraversal.hasNot() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [label, tagged]`

How would I phrase this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `not()` filter step:

```
g.V().hasLabel('tag').not(inE('tagged')).drop()
```

Comment: Excellent -- do you have any recommendations for guides / learning material?  I often check the reference (http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference) before posting here, but it's not the clearest documentation.

Comment: the "Reference Documentation" is largely for that - reference. it's not a book style. if you'd like more of a paced reading experience then you need Practical Gremlin - http://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html